# Where is the Kassa Fabrication shop on the citadel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

From my ship, I can purchase things that are available for purchase on the Citadel, but there is a 10% markup. Right now I can purchase from Sirta Supplies, Kassa Fabrication, and Spectre Requisitions.

[image]

I've found the shops for Spectre Requisitions and Sirta Supplies on the Citadel, but I can't find the one for Kassa Fabrication. I'd like to buy from the Citadel rather than my ship so I can save 10%. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's located on the Presidium commons, in the middle of the area.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like I couldn't find it because I don't have access to it yet! Do you know when this unlocks?

Comment: Not sure. I think it was available on my 2nd or 3rd trip to the Citadel.